# Count the values from a dataframe, to populate a variable in another dataframe (which specifies the counts required)

Tags: r, dataframe, count, reference

I have a summary table which is a reference of all the variables and possible values contained in another dataframe. I need to create a new variable which is a count of those variable values from the other dataframe.
Here is some example data,

```
# the dataframe with data I want to count from
Y1 <- c(1,2,3,2,4,4,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,4,4,4,3,2,1,2)
Y2 <- c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1)
Y3 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(Y1,Y2)

# the summary table with all variables and their possible values
Variable <- c("Y1","Y1","Y1","Y1","Y1","Y2","Y2","Y3", "Y3")
Values <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,2)
summary <- data.frame(Variable,Values)

>summary                            
  Variable Values
1       Y1      1
2       Y1      2
3       Y1      3
4       Y1      4
5       Y1      5
6       Y2      1
7       Y2      2
8       Y3      1
9       Y3      2
```

The summary contains the variable names and all the possible values. I need to create variable with a count of those variable and values, from the df dataframe. The example data is simulated so that Y1 and Y3, have no values for 5 and 2 respectively.

I imagine in words it would be describes as, the new_variable_count[i] in "summary" table, equals the count from "df", where (in "summary" table) variable[i] = value[i].

Some context, if it helps. In a questionnaire, asking people to rate something 1-5, you may get no responses for 5 out of 5. The value of 5 is possible, but if you run a frequency table of the variable you'll just get a count of values 1-4. Even if you reshape the data the possible values would not exist. How would a machine, without context, know what values should exist. Zero counts are actually useful when analysing 100s of variables, also if you don't know the possible value range of a variable you may incorrectly assume the values counted are the only values that exist.

Any help would be great. Any advice or direction will also be immensely helpful, ie. Is it better to use a loop? or is there a built-in function? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does table(df$Variable, df$Values) work?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question, I am quite sure there is already a built-in function but have no idea which one sorry.

However, a solution could be easily achieved with the tidyverse package and 2 for loops:
First you produce the summary table

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "question", values_to = "answer") %>% 
  group_by(question,answer) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()-> test
```

Then you check for each question (first for loop) if any of the possible answers are not present in the test df. If not it means that there is 0 answer and thus we add with rbind the line which represents for the q question and the i possible answer that there was no answer (0).

```
possible_answers <- 1:5
for(q in colnames(df)){
  print(q)
  for(i in possible_answers){
  if (! i %in% filter(test, question == q)$answer){
    print(i)
    test %>% 
      rbind(c(q,i,0)) -> test
    }
  }
}
```

final df visualisation:

```
test %>% 
  arrange(question,answer)
```

I am quite sure there is a more "elegant" way to performe this.
You can also do the summary df with base R data manipulation if you do not want to use tidyverse package.

Tom

Comment: Not quite, but it gives me an idea! It maybe simpler than I thought. I can take the tidyverse top part of your code. Then use your "test" df to merge to the summary df, using the two columns of both dataframes as ID variable. After the merge anything that isn't present will have missing/NAs, which is what I wanted. Btw, many many thanks!